# How to test rate limits with Amazon SES PHP API

Tags: php, email, amazon-ses

I have Amazon SES up and running with the PHP API.

In the documentation it says that:

> Reaching Sending Limits with the Amazon SES API
>
> If your application attempts to send an email beyond your sending
>   limits, the application will encounter a throttling error. The
>   following are types of throttling errors that you might see:
>
> ```
> Daily message quota exceeded
>
> Maximum sending rate exceeded
> ```
>
> A throttling error might occur because of incorrect predictions of
>   email volume, or bursts of transactional email that are higher than
>   expected. To handle a throttling error, program your application to
>   wait for a random interval of between 0 and 10 minutes, and then retry
>   the send request.

But how can you test the code that deals with the occasion where the maximum sending rate has been exceeded? Do you have to send multiple requests to $client->sendEmail with success@simulator.amazonses.com until it maxes out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The practical solution to this is by mocking the [`SesClient`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.Ses.SesClient.html) class (via extension) and have that return an error or success return value at random.

The positive side effect is that no emails are actually sent.

Answer (score 1):

The Amazon SES API provides the GetSendQuota action, which returns your sending limits. When you call GetSendQuota action, you receive the following information:

- Number of emails you have sent during the past 24 hours
- Sending quota for the current 24-hour period
- Maximum send rate

See [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_GetSendQuota.html)

Comment: Thanks for this, but the question is, how to test the application if it goes over the maximum send rate. How would, for example, the following throttling code be tested? http://sesblog.amazon.com/post/TxKR75VKOYDS60/How-to-handle-a-quot-Throttling-Maximum-sending-rate-exceeded-quot-error